# How to extend a MarionetteJS module to reduce code duplication

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, module, marionette, extend

I've got a notifications toolbar which is a module. Very similar to the notifications toolbar in the facebook native app. In this toolbar are 3 regions:

- InvitesRegion
- RequestsRegion
- NotificationsRegion

Each of these regions contains their own module (InvitesModule, RequestsModule, NotificationsModule). Each, however, has the exact same functionality:

- Check the server for new (Invites|Requests|Notifications)
- If found, update the associated region
- And then a whole bunch of other functions (click to popup the collectionView etc..)

Can I write a single module, say the InvitesModule and have my other two module extend that module so that I can just overwrite the variable I need to?

Thanks and please let me know if I can be more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why yes, yes you can! While Marionette doesn't exactly allow you to create a "base module" per se, it does allow you to modify an existing module. We've taken advantage of this in our application to create a `ModuleDefaults` definition that we use for all templates. Here's how it works:

```
var ModuleDefaults = {
  // Define baseline behavior to share among all modules
  definition: function() {
    this.foo = 'bar';

    this.addInitializer(function() {
      console.log(this.moduleName + ': do startup stuff');
    });
  }
};
```

Now you can create modules that simply implement this behavior like so:

```
// Create a module with the default implementation
App.module('Module1', ModuleDefaults.definition);
```

Or you can create a module that overrides this bevavior:

```
// Create another module with the default implementation
App.module('Module2', ModuleDefaults.definition);

// Provide customizations to second module:
App.module('Module2', function() {
  // override existing behavior
  this.foo = 'baz';

  // add new behavior
  this.addFinalizer(function() {
    console.log(this.moduleName + ': cleanup stuff');
  });
});
```

Using this technique, prove the `foo` property of the second module is overridden:

```
App.start();                  // -> Module1: do startup stuff
                              // -> Module2: do startup stuff
console.log(App.Module1.foo); // -> bar
console.log(App.Module2.foo); // -> baz
App.Module1.stop();           // -> 
App.Module2.stop();           // -> Module2: cleanup stuff
```

Comment: Chris, thanks for taking the time to show me. That's a great solution