# Reusing component in several marionette.js projects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I've watched all the videos on [backbonerails.com](http://backbonerails.com) and I've started using marionette.js in client apps with great joy.
I've reached a point where I'm comfortable using it in large scale apps and I've deployed a few already. But I can't figure out how to reuse components in different projects.

The thing is that it's all encapsualted in an "app" module with submodules. How can I have certain reuseable modules that aren't attached directly to the app but still has access to it when being used.

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Modules` let you "define" them multiple times; each subsequent "definition" lets you overwrite the existing capability. One thing you could do is create a `BaseModuleDefinition` function that contains your base implementation, pass it into the `Application`'s `module` call along with the module name, and then call `module` again to provide customization.

I posted an example of this here:
[How to extend a MarionetteJS module to reduce code duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500984/how-to-extend-a-marionettejs-module-to-reduce-code-duplication/18503002#18503002)