# 2 Backbone.Marionette applications sharing some functionality

Tags: javascript, marionette

I need 2 create 2 Backbone.Marionette applications which are pretty similar but could have differences in their functionality and views. So, I would like them to share some things but still be able to redefine.

Which way would you choose to solve this task?

Nice, if someone might share a link to a GitHub repo with the same problem been solved.

Answer (score 0):

`Marionette` has a construct called [`Modules`](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md) that is probably what you want to use to split up features to be shared across multiple `Marionette` applications.

Answer (score 0):

Marionette lets you do this out of the box, although the mechanism is a little different than you might be used to. Marionette modules are defined by calling `MyApp.module(moduleName)`. You can make this call as many times as you want; any subsequent definitions will override prior ones. Armed with this knowledge, you could create a `ModuleDefaults` module definition, then use it to create your baseline behavior for each module, then "redefine" the module with module-specific overrides.

I provide an example here:
[How to extend a MarionetteJS module to reduce code duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500984/how-to-extend-a-marionettejs-module-to-reduce-code-duplication/18503002#18503002)